# constructing a increment value and decrements

Tags: android, user-interface, android-emulator

how can I do the the gui in the picture, like the increment value and decrements, first I thought that there are three buttons one on the top of other but,maybe there is something else. Here is a pic of it  [image]

Comment: you mean `date picker` and `time picker`??

Comment: are those importet in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)?

NumberPicker is the basic UI element (+ button, plus a number editor, plus a - button) that is used to build up the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html).